# How to format a nested dictionary that contains nested list using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like the like the below one:

```
newDict = {dataset_name: {model_name: {method_1: [[Value_1, value_2, so on]], model_2: [[Value_1, value_2, so on]] }}}
```

Say, I have 2 dataset (`dataset_1, dataset_2`), 2 models (`model_1`, `model_2`), and 2 methods for each model (`method_1, method_2`)

I am using this code to convart the `newDict` into a pandas df.

`newdict= pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, "index") for k, v in newdict.items()}, axis=0)`

The df I am getting like the below one

```
                        method_1                                                  method_2
dataset_1   model_1     [[value_1, value_2]], method_2: [[value_1, value_2]]    [[value_1, value_2]], method_2: [[value_1, value_2]]
dataset_2   model_2     [[value_1, value_2]], method_2: [[value_1, value_2]]    [[value_1, value_2]], method_2: [[value_1, value_2]]
```

Could you tell me what I have to do to convert the `newDict` into this format

```
                            dataset_1           dataset_2
model_1     method_1        value_1, value_2    value_1, value_2
            method_2
model_2     method_1
            method_2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Toy data as per your indications
data = {
    "dataset_1": {
        "model_1": {"method_1": [[1, 2, 3, 4]], "method_2": [[5, 6, 7, 8]]},
        "model_2": {"method_1": [[9, 10, 11, 12]]},
        "model_3": {"method_1": [[13, 14, 15, 16]]},
    },
    "dataset_2": {
        "model_1": {"method_1": [[17, 18, 19, 20]], "method_2": [[21, 22, 23, 24]]},
        "model_2": {"method_1": [[25, 26, 27, 28]]},
        "model_3": {"method_1": [[29, 30, 31, 32]]},
    },
}

# Reshape the data as a new dict
newDict = {
    (dataset, model, method): values
    for dataset, innerDict in pd.DataFrame(data).iteritems()
    for model, method_and_values in innerDict.iteritems()
    for method, values in method_and_values.items()
}

# Make a Dataframe and transpose it
newdf = pd.DataFrame(newDict).T

# Slice the dataframe (one df per dataset) and store slices in a list 
list_of_dfs = [
    newdf[newdf.index.get_level_values(0) == dataset].droplevel(0)
    for dataset in data.keys()
]

# Create a new dataframe from the list of datframes
df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1)

# Rename columns
df.columns = [dataset for dataset in data.keys()]

print(df)

# Outputs
                         dataset_1         dataset_2
model_1 method_1      [1, 2, 3, 4]  [17, 18, 19, 20]
        method_2      [5, 6, 7, 8]  [21, 22, 23, 24]
model_2 method_1   [9, 10, 11, 12]  [25, 26, 27, 28]
model_3 method_1  [13, 14, 15, 16]  [29, 30, 31, 32]
```